# Payed a company to draw a picture

Tags: united-kingdom

I purchased a drawing to be commissioned by a company who is mainly based in Asia and the Uk, but they have artists that work for them all over the world. This was on November 1st 2019, they sent me the first rough copy in drop box on November 17th 2019 to ether approve or decline. I requested for the picture to be edited and I've been ignored on both their FB and website platform since then. When i told them i wanted a refund they finally answered me and told me they could not do it from their FB account and to contact their support email. On their website it says;

Is there anything I'm able to do it has been two months since purchasing the service, searching the company name I've found multiple other people that have very similar stories as mine. I am wondering about the legal rights of an artist and product (picture) but also the partnership as a whole and their accountability as a business. I as a customer purchased a product and did not receive the product at all.

please help

Comment: Did you use their email for contact and did they just ignore you? Did you send them a letter by physical mail?

Comment: I contacted them through their fb account where it showed they read my.message and never replied. I've also tried through email and their website support tool that is through email as well.

Comment: You got scammed. If you want to do anything about it, you need to contact law enforcement and/or a lawyer of your own. Nothing we can do here will help you any more than that.